# MVC3 jquery.validate.unobtrusive override options without editing source?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, unobtrusive-validation

just wondering if there is a way to override the highlight and unhighlight options when using mvc3 jquery.validate.unobtrusive without editing the source js file...

I already tried:

```
var elementToValidate = $(element);
        var form = $(element.form);
        if (form.length) {
            //elementToValidate.valid();
            form.validate({
                highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
                    $(element).closest('td').addClass('alert-error error');
                }, unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
                    $(element).closest('td').addClass('alert-error error');
                }
            });
        }
```

but highlight and unhighlight aren't overridden unless i remove the unobtrusive library from my scripts..

If i edit the source of jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js It seems to work just perfectly:

```
function validationInfo(form) {
        var $form = $(form),
            result = $form.data(data_validation);

        if (!result) {
            result = {
                options: {  // options structure passed to jQuery Validate's validate() method
                    errorClass: "input-validation-error",
                    errorElement: "span",
                    errorPlacement: $.proxy(onError, form),
                    invalidHandler: $.proxy(onErrors, form),
                    messages: {},
                    rules: {},
                    success: $.proxy(onSuccess, form),
                    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
                        $(element).closest('td').addClass('alert-error error');
                    }, unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
                        $(element).closest('td').addClass('alert-error error');
                    }
                },
                attachValidation: function () {
                    $form.validate(this.options);
                },
                validate: function () {  // a validation function that is called by unobtrusive Ajax
                    $form.validate();
                    return $form.valid();
                }
            };
            $form.data(data_validation, result);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

just wondering if anyone has come up with a way to override the options without having to modify the source..

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can change the jquery validator defaults:

```
$.validator.defaults.highlight = function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    $(element).closest('td').addClass('alert-error error');
};
$.validator.defaults.unhighlight = function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    $(element).closest('td').addClass('alert-error error');
};
```

Execute this before execution of the `onload` event (i.e., do not call this in `$(document).ready()`, but directly).